# Failed to acquire token silently using WebApp after login using Azure AD?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I have WebApp and WebAPI register into same Azure AD.

I'm trying to call WebAPI from WebApp.

I have added service WebAPI into my WebApp in azure AD Applcaition. like below -
 [image]

When I run WebAPI it will give me login screen after login success I can access WebAPI methods. This is normal behavior.

When I run WebApp it will act same login screen and after login success i can see WebApp.

Now I want to call WebAPI methods from WebApp but I do not want login screen for WebAPI because When I will run WebApp i will get login screen
and after login I hope by using same user I should able to access WebAPI without again doing login stuff , as i have token which will work for both
WebApp and WebAPI.

WebAPI code -

Startup.Auth.cs

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
        private static string aadInstance = EnsureTrailingSlash(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"]);
        private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
        private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

        public static readonly string Authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

        // This is the resource ID of the AAD Graph API.  We'll need this to request a token to call the Graph API.
        string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = Authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                       AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) => 
                       {
                           var code = context.Code;
                           ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                           string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                           AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                           AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                               code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId).Result;

                           return Task.FromResult(0);
                       }
                    }
                });
        }

        private static string EnsureTrailingSlash(string value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                value = string.Empty;
            }

            if (!value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                return value + "/";
            }

            return value;
        }
    }
```

TestController.cs

```
[Authorize]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/getdata")]
        public IEnumerable<string> GetData()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
```

WebApp code -

```
Startup.Auth.cs

 public partial class Startup
    {
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
        private static string aadInstance = EnsureTrailingSlash(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"]);
        private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
        private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

        public static readonly string Authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

        // This is the resource ID of the AAD Graph API.  We'll need this to request a token to call the Graph API.
        string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = Authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                       AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) => 
                       {
                           var code = context.Code;
                           ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                           string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                           AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                           AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                               code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId).Result;

                           return Task.FromResult(0);
                       }
                    }
                });
        }

        private static string EnsureTrailingSlash(string value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                value = string.Empty;
            }

            if (!value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                return value + "/";
            }

            return value;
        }
    }
```

HomeController.cs

```
[Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private static string clientIdWebApp = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:clientIdWebApp"];
        private static string clientIdWebApi = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:clientIdWebApi"];
        private static string clientSecretWebApp = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:clientSecretWebApp"];
        private static string aadInstance = (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"]);
        private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
        private static string PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
        Uri redirectUri = new Uri(PostLogoutRedirectUri);
        public static readonly string Authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

        public ActionResult Index()
        {          
                return View();
        }

        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
            try
            {
                AuthenticationResult result = null;

                string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier").Value;
                AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.Authority, new ADALTokenCache(userObjectID));
                ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientIdWebApp, clientSecretWebApp);
                //AcquireTokenSilentAsync should have to work as i'm accessing WebAPI using same user I logged in to WebApp 
                result = authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(clientIdWebApi,credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId)).Result;
                // gettign exception {"Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken"} but I got match id into cache. 
        // and if use AcquireToken instead then it works but api response is login html //page instead of api output 
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://MYWEBAPI/api/getdata");
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                // Return the user's profile in the view.
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (AdalException ex)
            {
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

AdalTokenCache.cs  - same for both WebApp and WebAPI

```
 public class ADALTokenCache : TokenCache
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        private string userId;
        private UserTokenCache Cache;

        public ADALTokenCache(string signedInUserId)
        {
            // associate the cache to the current user of the web app
            userId = signedInUserId;
            this.AfterAccess = AfterAccessNotification;
            this.BeforeAccess = BeforeAccessNotification;
            this.BeforeWrite = BeforeWriteNotification;
            // look up the entry in the database
            Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
            // place the entry in memory
            this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.cacheBits,"ADALCache"));
        }

        // clean up the database
        public override void Clear()
        {
            base.Clear();
            var cacheEntry = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
            db.UserTokenCacheList.Remove(cacheEntry);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        // Notification raised before ADAL accesses the cache.
        // This is your chance to update the in-memory copy from the DB, if the in-memory version is stale
        void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            if (Cache == null)
            {
                // first time access
                Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
            }
            else
            { 
                // retrieve last write from the DB
                var status = from e in db.UserTokenCacheList
                             where (e.webUserUniqueId == userId)
                select new
                {
                    LastWrite = e.LastWrite
                };

                // if the in-memory copy is older than the persistent copy
                if (status.First().LastWrite > Cache.LastWrite)
                {
                    // read from from storage, update in-memory copy
                    Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
                }
            }
            this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.cacheBits, "ADALCache"));
        }

        // Notification raised after ADAL accessed the cache.
        // If the HasStateChanged flag is set, ADAL changed the content of the cache
        void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            // if state changed
            if (this.HasStateChanged)
            {
                if (Cache == null)
                {
                    Cache = new UserTokenCache
                    {
                        webUserUniqueId = userId
                    };
                }

                Cache.cacheBits = MachineKey.Protect(this.Serialize(), "ADALCache");
                Cache.LastWrite = DateTime.Now;

                // update the DB and the lastwrite 
                db.Entry(Cache).State = Cache.UserTokenCacheId == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                this.HasStateChanged = false;
            }
        }

        void BeforeWriteNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            // if you want to ensure that no concurrent write take place, use this notification to place a lock on the entry
        }

        public override void DeleteItem(TokenCacheItem item)
        {
            base.DeleteItem(item);
        }
    }
```

Most Important I found that webapi also having `AccountController` with below same code for sign in like webapp do. what should be done in such case?

```
 public class AccountController : BaseMvcController
    {
        public void SignIn()
        {
            // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }

        public void SignOut()
        {
            string callbackUrl = Url.Action("SignOutCallback", "Account", routeValues: null, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }

        public ActionResult SignOutCallback()
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // Redirect to home page if the user is authenticated.
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AcquireTokenSilentAsync` method can help you only if you only if your application already acquired a valid token for the target resource (in your case backend Web API) at least once before and has that token cached for subsequent use.

You are probably getting this error because you haven't really authenticated to the Web API even once (i.e. acquired a valid token for the Web API and passed that even once), so there is nothing available to be used from the cache.

Simply put, you would not be able to use AcquireTokenSilentAsync to authenticate the first time.

For further understanding, look at the GitHub example that you have shared as part of your question itself. [Secure a backend web API](https://github.com/mspnp/architecture-center/blob/master/docs/multitenant-identity/web-api.md)

- The sample code first gets a valid token for the Web API using Authorization Code flow.
- Only once the first valid token is there, it gets cached and subsequent calls can be tackled by `authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync`. This is clearly stated as part of sample documentation as well.

> - resourceID. The App ID URI of the web API, which you created when you registered the web API in Azure AD
> - tokenCache. An object that caches the access tokens. See Token caching.
>
> If AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync succeeds, ADAL caches the
>   token. Later, you can get the token from the cache by calling
>   AcquireTokenSilentAsync

**Code from sample**

1. To get the valid token first time using Authorization Code Flow

   // The OpenID Connect middleware sends this event when it gets the authorization code.

   ```
   public override async Task AuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context)
   {
       string authorizationCode = context.ProtocolMessage.Code;
       string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID
       string resourceID = "https://tailspin.onmicrosoft.com/surveys.webapi" // App ID URI
       ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

       AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, tokenCache);
       AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
       authorizationCode, new Uri(redirectUri), credential, resourceID);

       // If successful, the token is in authResult.AccessToken
   }
   ```
2. Later, you can get the token from the cache by calling AcquireTokenSilentAsync:

   ```
   AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, tokenCache);
   var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resourceID, credential, new UserIdentifier(userId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
   ```

Comment: where I can write this `AuthorizationCodeReceived` inside my MVC application ? ON Index.cshtml I'm trying to invoke Other Webapi which is inside same azure AD using HttpClient and i do not have clientSecret for that other webapi i only have client id with me. what could be done in that case?

Comment: You will get that `AuthorizationCodeReceived` event only if you use the Authorization code flow in your web application. Look at the sample code associated with the github sample you mentioned in your question. It has entire repository with full code for web app and web api. Basically, the web app will provide a signin screen to user. Also, consider whether you really need user's identity in web api or not? You need user identity in api if it makes authorization decisions based on users, if it doesn't then you can use application identity. Code in github sample uses delegated user identity.

Comment: code in github uses .net core project :( i'm using web mvc project ... yes i'm able to got success till web mvc project .. it will open login popup and when login i'm at home page of web app i.e Index.cshtml now on this index.cshtml I want to access web api which is register into same Azure AD and i dont have client secret of this web api .. can you update code snippet ?

Comment: hmm.. ok.. code will differ for you a little bit then.. but authentication part should be similar.. btw.. the secret the sample code is looking for is not the web api.. but the one for web app

Comment: The code snippet you're looking for is in SurveysTokenService.cs.. public async Task<AuthenticationResult> RequestTokenAsync(.. method. Even the comments put in for GetTokenForWebApiAsync point you to the same method.. This method retrieves the access token for the WebAPI resource that has previously
        /// been retrieved and cached. This method will fail if an access token for the WebAPI 
        /// resource has not been retrieved and cached. You can use the RequestAccessTokenAsync
        /// method to retrieve and cache access tokens.

Comment: Take a look at this sample.. very close to what you're trying to do - This does exactly the same thing as other GitHub sample, but with ASP.NET MVC and not .NET core.. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect .. and specifically at ToDoListController.cs .. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Controllers/TodoListController.cs

Comment: let me update my full code into question please guide me.