# What is the difference between UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication with UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I have webapi which is registered into azure AD.
which is having below code in Startup.Auth.cs

```
   public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = ClientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = PostLogoutRedirectUri
            });
```

When I run this webapi in browser it ask for login and after login success able to see all api's url.

I'm trying to access this secured api from web app which is register into same azure AD.

When I use `AcquireTokenAsync` into Webapp to generate access token for this webapi it works but gives login html page as response.

To avoid this I tried to generate silent token using `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` but exception occurs `unable to generate token cache not found` but cache key found still exception there .

After some google git post suggest to use `UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication` this code into WebApi and they said it will return output of api when call from webapp instead login page output , but it doesn't work.

```
 app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
                    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                    TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An API should not require a user to login. The second option with Bearer token authentication is correct. That means your client app needs to acquire an access token and pass it with the HTTP requests.

`AcquireTokenAsync` and `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` work a bit differently from how you think.
The first one takes some arguments and then calls the /oauth2/token endpoint of the AAD authority to get an access token *unless it has an access token in cache already*.
The silent version only checks the cache, and throws an exception if it cannot find one.

So your client app would usually use one of the `AcquireTokenAsync` variants to get an access token and a refresh token.
When you do that, ADAL will store the tokens in the token cache you have given it (or the in-memory cache by default).
Then later in your code you can use the silent version to get tokens as you can expect them to be in the cache.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. can you help me here pls m stucked up... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52745656/failed-to-acquire-token-silently-using-webapp-after-login-using-azure-ad/

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET OWIN components include middleware specifically designed to secure web API via Azure AD and OAuth2 bearer token access. OpenID Connect middleware (`UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`) fires when the requests come to UX controllers which serve UX to the browser, where as Azure AD OAuth2 bearer token middleware (`UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication`) fires only when the request is for a web API.